# Engine noise / rattle when clutch is fully pressed [BMW 320d e46, manual]

Tags: clutch, 320d

I have a strange noise, like a rattling/stomping sound at idle, when pressing the clutch pedal. The clutch and the flywheel (DMF), were both changed with new parts.

Except for that sound, the car handles perfectly.

Has anyone came across something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Was the throwout bearing changed?

Comment: Yes, it came with the new clutch and DMF in the same package. Maybe it was wise to add that I replaced the OEM clutch with aftermarket (LuK). The replacement was done by professional mechanics, not by myself... afterwards, they investigated what could cause the rattling/stomping, they checked the crackshaft and other components, and in the end they said that they can't figure out what's causing it. Hence, I'm here... maybe I get lucky :-)

Comment: My only suggestion might be the DMF is bad. From what I know of DMFs, there are a few moving parts in them. If it wasn't put together correctly, you might hear something when the clutch is disengaged.

Comment: I really hope I'm not that unlucky - buy a new clutch+DMF and DMF proves to be bad. Another thing that I noticed today is that, when running at high RPMs, engaging the clutch creates an even worse, very noticeable, stomping sound coming from the engine.

Comment: If the engine wasn't making any of these noises prior to the clutch/DMF install, you really have to look at what was changed, not at the engine itself. With the DMF attached directly to the back of the engine, you could easily mistake *any* noises from it as though it were coming from the engine itself. I'd take it back to the shop and have them diagnose again with that in mind. They have probably already figured it out, but don't want to tear the whole thing apart again under warranty.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bad throwout bearing. A bad DMF should make noise when no pressure is applied to the clutch, while a throwout bearing starts making a ruckus when you do. Might be a bad replacement job, lots of things can rattle, take it back to the mechanics. You won't know what's bad for certain without disassembly, good luck.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Well... long story short, the crankshaft broke. No idea how that happened, though. I had the engine replaced entirely... so that closes this topic. :)

Comment: @A1rwalker  That's a brutal conclusion and I'll say that I didn't expect to hear you had a broken crankshaft.  Can you answer your own question and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OP's [last comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22006/engine-noise-rattle-when-clutch-is-fully-pressed-bmw-320d-e46-manual#comment44630_22006), the rattle was due to a broken crankshaft.

I will add one thing though. When I was a kid, my father had a '91 Mitsubishi Pajero that suddenly had its crankshaft snap in two. He was able to drive it to the dealership with a rattling noise that was present regardless of clutch position or RPM.

With regards to the OP's case, I am quite frankly surprised that the rattling noise was present only with the clutch pressed in. Not saying that it isn't possible, just unusual that the OP was able to drive "normally" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

They could have left a loose bolt on the preasure plate for the clutch and when you disengage the clutch, the bolt might hit the shell of the trany.